# ¿Cómo se haría correctamente el destructor y la sobrecarga del operator= de esta clase? C++

Tags: c++, lista, sobrecarga-de-operadores, sobrecarga

Pues me está rallando demasiado porque el programa compila bien pero peta y no entiendo porque. Yo creo que es por el destructor y la sobrecarga operator= porque las demás funciones me parecen relativamente sencillas la verdad.

La clase:

```
#include "Node.h"

class LlistaDoble
{
public:
    LlistaDoble();
    ~LlistaDoble();

    bool empty() const;
    Node* begin() const;
    Node* rbegin() const;
    Node* insert(const int& valor, Node* posicio);
    Node* erase(Node* posicio);
    void unique();
    void merge(LlistaDoble& llista);
    LlistaDoble& operator=(const LlistaDoble& llista);

    void setPrimero(Node* primero) { m_primero = primero; }
    void setUltimo(Node* ultimo) { m_ultimo = ultimo; }
    Node* getPrimero() { return m_primero; }
    Node* getUltimo() { return m_ultimo; }
private:
    Node* m_primero;
    Node* m_ultimo;
};
```

Destructor:

```
LlistaDoble::~LlistaDoble()
{
    if (m_primero != nullptr)
    {
        while (m_primero != nullptr)
            m_primero = erase(m_primero);
    }

    if (m_ultimo != nullptr)
        delete m_ultimo;
}
```

Sobrecarga del operador=:

```
LlistaDoble& LlistaDoble::operator=(const LlistaDoble& llista)
{
    if (this != &llista)
    {
        Node* aux;

        if (m_primero != nullptr)
        {
            while (m_primero != nullptr)
                m_primero = erase(m_primero);
        }

        if (m_ultimo != nullptr)
        {
            delete m_ultimo;
            m_ultimo = nullptr;
        }

        if (llista.m_primero != nullptr)
        {
            m_primero = insert(llista.m_primero->getValor(), nullptr);
            aux = llista.m_primero;
            aux = aux->getNext();

            while (aux != nullptr)
            {
                m_ultimo = insert(aux->getValor(), nullptr);
                aux = aux->getNext();
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

En la sobrecarga para copiar la lista que le paso por parámetro me ayudo de un auxiliar que lo igualo al primer elemento de la lista y voy recorriendo la lista. La función insert si le pasó un nullptr me añade un nodo al final de la lista. La función erase borra elemento que hay en la posicion que le paso.

Comment: deberías añadir la implementación de `erase` y de `insert`